# Using Linq to run a method on a collection of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

This is a long shot, I know...

Let's say I have a collection

```
List<MyClass> objects;
```

and I want to run the same method on every object in the collection, with or without a return value.  Before Linq I would have said:

```
List<ReturnType> results = new List<ReturnType>();
List<int> FormulaResults = new List<int>();
foreach (MyClass obj in objects) {
  results.Add(obj.MyMethod());
  FormulaResults.Add(ApplyFormula(obj));
}
```

I would **love** to be able to do something like this:

```
List<ReturnType> results = new List<ReturnType>();
results.AddRange(objects.Execute(obj => obj.MyMethod())); 
// obviously .Execute() above is fictitious
List<int> FormulaResults = new List<int>();
FormulaResults.AddRange(objects.Execute(obj => ApplyFormula(obj)));
```

I haven't found anything that will do this.  Is there such a thing?

If there's nothing generic like I've posited above, at least maybe there's a way of doing it for the purposes I'm working on now: I have a collection of one object that has a wrapper class:

```
class WrapperClass {
  private WrappedClass wrapped;
  public WrapperClass(WrappedClass wc) {
    this.wrapped = wc;
  }
}
```

My code has a collection `List<WrappedClass> objects` and I want to convert that to a `List<WrapperClass>`.  Is there some clever Linq way of doing this, without doing the tedious

```
List<WrapperClass> result = new List<WrapperClass>();
foreach (WrappedClass obj in objects)
  results.Add(new WrapperClass(obj));
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Would:

```
results.AddRange(objects.Select(obj => ApplyFormula(obj)));
```

do?

or (simpler)

```
var results = objects.Select(obj => ApplyFormula(obj)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the Select() extension method can do what you're looking for:

```
objects.Select( obj => obj.MyMethod() ).ToList(); // produces List<Result> 

objects.Select( obj => ApplyFormula(obj) ).ToList(); // produces List<int>
```

Same thing for the last case:

```
objects.Select( obj => new WrapperClass( obj ) ).ToList();
```

If you have a `void` method which you want to call, here's a trick you can use with IEnumerable, which doesn't have a ForEach() extension, to create a similar behavior without a lot of effort.

```
objects.Select( obj => { obj.SomeVoidMethod(); false; } ).Count();
```

The `Select()` will produce a sequence of `[false]` values after invoking `SomeVoidMethod()` on each `[obj]` in the objects sequence. Since `Select()` uses deferred execution, we call the `Count()` extension to force each element in the sequence to be evaluated. It works quite well when you want something like a `ForEach()` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If the method `MyMethod` that you want to apply returns an object of type `T` then you can obtain an `IEnumerable<T>` of the result of the method via:

```
var results = objects.Select(o => o.MyMethod());
```

If the method `MyMethod` that you want to apply has return type `void` then you can apply the method via:

```
objects.ForEach(o => o.MyMethod());
```

This assumes that `objects` is of generic type `List<>`. If all you have is an `IEnumerable<>` then you can [roll your own](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) `ForEach` extension method or apply `objects.ToList()` first and use the above syntax .

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler maps a LINQ select onto the .Select extension method, defined over IEnumerable (or IQueryable which we'll ignore here).  Actually, that .Select method is exactly the kind of projection function that you're after.

LBushkin is correct, but you can actually use LINQ syntax as well...

```
var query = from o in objects
   select o.MyMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also run a custom method using the marvelous Jon Skeet's [morelinq library](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

For example if you had a text property on your MyClass that you needed to change in runtime using a method on the same class:

```
objects = objects.Pipe<MyClass>(class => class.Text = class.UpdateText()).ToList();
```

This method will now be implemented on every object in your list. I love morelinq!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/UpdateOperator.ashx has an extended Update method you can use. Or you can use a select statement as posted by others.